# What is the key length of shared secret by Curve 25519 ECDH

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman

Both parties uses Curve 25519 key pairs for ECDH key exchange. What is the key length of shared secret after ECDH?

Comment: Hint: Of what type is a DH shared secret usually? How big is that type for Curve25519?

Comment: @SEJPM: the standard 32-byte curve25519 for ecdh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [this](https://cr.yp.to/ecdh/curve25519-20060209.pdf) paper you can find nearly everything about Curve25519. In the section "Specification" you find the answer:

> {Curve25519 secret keys} × {Curve25519 public keys} →
>   {Curve25519 public keys}

this is the function, which is calculated for a key exchange. So the shared secret key has the same properties as the public keys:

> { $q: q \in ${ $0,1,...,2^{256 - 1}$}}

This matches, what Bernstein says in the introduction: The key length (for both public and private) are 32 byte long. And in that format they are stored. In other words every key is 256 bits long.

In [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/72134/raw-curve25519-public-key-points) post you see an example for these keys.